# How to switch from default npmjs repo to Artifactory repo in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, repository, artifactory

I'm developing an Angular application and until now I have been using the default npm repository (registry.npmjs.org). Now I need to switch to using Artifactory and update my project accordingly.

I already changed the registry with:

```
 npm config set registry (myArtifactoryRemoteRepoURL)
```

Then, after deleting the nodes_module folder I ran the npm install command:

```
 npm i
```

I also tried:

```
 npm i --package-lock
```

The modules are still loaded from the default npmjs registry. I guess this is because in the package-lock.json the dependencies are still resolved to default repo URLs. So I would probably have to update the package-lock.json somehow.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json` (as well as `node_modules`) and running `npm install` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `package-lock.json` file entirely (and the `node_modules` as well). Those will be regenerated when you run `npm install`.